# Mongo::Error::SocketError: Broken pipe when executing queries in a mongo replica set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I randomly get this error from my rails app connected to a mongo replica set. This then leads to the server description getting changed to 'unknown' and server selection starting all over again.

This doesn't happen when I try running the app in local connected to a standalone mongod server.

For some reason, connecting to a replica set and executing repeated queries on it results in

`Read retry due to: Mongo::Error::SocketError EOFError: end of file reached`

Is this an issue with the underlining SSL/TLS connection to the replica set? I've tried increasing the socket_timeout, connection_timeout in my mongoid.yml with no success.

Comment: Maybe add the version of MongoDB and mongo driver. Also the mongodb.yml fail might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the server closes the connection to the client. One time when *that* happens is when a replica set has an election - the old primary closes all of its connections with MongoDB 4.0 and earlier (not with 4.2+).

Since the read is retried, the situation does not generally affect the  application other than the diagnostic message being printed that you see.

You can look into the server logs at the time when the message is printed to see why the server closed the connection. Sometimes connections are closed without server-side logging (for example, when the server process terminates it doesn't log all connection closes).

Comment: So the cluster has an election even when the primary node is available? So there's no way to avoid this issue other than set a high server_selection_timeout?

Comment: A replica set may hold elections when it has a primary, due to the priorities of the members. Server selection timeout has no bearing on the situation.